# Using REST controllers in Zend Framework 2 - map additional “action” methods (e.g. create form)

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to use REST controllers in my website to map to routes similar to the following:

```
GET /article
GET /article/1
GET /article/create
GET /article/1/update
GET /article/1/delete
POST /article
PUT /article/1
DELETE /article/1
```

My controller is:

```
namespace Article\Controller;

// use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Article\Form\ArticleForm;
use Article\Model\Article;

class ArticleController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
    protected $articleTable;

    public function getList()
    {
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'articles' => $this->getArticleTable()->fetchAll(),
        ));
    }

    public function get($id)
    {
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'article' => $this->getArticleTable()->getArticle($id),
        ));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $form = new ArticleForm();
        $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $article = new Article();
            $form->setInputFilter($article->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $article->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                $this->getArticleTable()->saveArticle($article);

                // Redirect to list of articles
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('article');
            }
        }
        return array('form' => $form);
    }

    public function update()
    {
        //...
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        //...
    }

    public function getArticleTable()
    {
        if (!$this->articleTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->articleTable = $sm->get('Article\Model\ArticleTable');
        }
        return $this->articleTable;
    }
}
```

My module.config.php routes are as following:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'article' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/article[/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Article\Controller\Article',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

With the `AbstractRestfulController` I can achieve the first two GETs, POST and DELETE; but, I don't know how to get the following routes (which will render as forms):

```
GET /article/create .. maps to ArticleController::create
GET /article/1/update .. maps to ArticleController::update
GET /article/1/delete .. maps to ArticleController::delete
```

I read in the docs: "Additionally, you can map “action” methods to the AbstractRestfulController, just as you would in the AbstractActionController; these methods will be suffixed with “Action”, differentiating them from the RESTful methods listed above. This allows you to perform such actions as providing forms used to submit to the various RESTful methods, or to add RPC methods to your RESTful API." .. but I can't see an example, and I tried adding a createAction but route not found. I guess my router configuration needs modified?